Invertibility of a $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ function
$\phi$ is invertible iff $\exists C>0 $ such that $|\phi(x)|\geq C$ almost everywhere on X. From here we can say $\phi$ is not invertible iff $\forall C>0$, $|\phi(x)|< C$ almost everywhere on X. Then how to show that $\mu(\{x\in X : |\phi(x)|< C\})>0$ for each $C>0$ ?

Let's unpack the statements. We want to negate
$$ \exists C>0 \text{ such that } \vert \phi(x)\vert\geq C \text{ almost everywhere on }X. $$
Let's rewrite this more formally. Almost everywhere means that it holds up to a set of measure zero, i.e. the statement becomes
$$ \exists C>0 \ : \ \mu(X\setminus \{ x\in X \ : \ \vert \phi(x)\vert \geq C\}) =0. $$
This can be simplified to
$$ \exists C>0 \ : \ \mu(\{ x\in X \ : \ \vert \phi(x)\vert<C\}) =0. $$
Now, the negation of that statement gives us
$$ \forall C>0 \ : \ \mu(\{ x\in X \ : \ \vert \phi(x) \vert <C\}) \neq 0. $$
However, measures (in this context) return only nonnegative numbers, thus, we get
$$ \forall C>0 \ : \ \mu(\{ x\in X \ : \ \vert \phi(x) \vert <C\}) > 0. $$

Thank you so much Mr. Severin. My doubt is about what will be if $\mu$ is complex valued measure ? Then can it not be negative?

@Halmos If you allow for a general complex measure, than it can be negative. Just consider a measure which is the negative of a probability measure (i.e. can only attain nonpositive real numbers).
